# Android set constant Button in more than 5 activity

Tags: android

Hi I am new to Android I want to Set One Button named (Click) in More than Five Activity  like Title of the Application at the Top.I did not want it to add on all the 5 activity Manually is there any simple way in Android?

Comment: What do you mean manually? Are you talking about adding a button and not having to implement an "onClick" method in every class?

Answer (score 1):

This is simple if you have one layout for all 5 activities, but you probably don't. So the solution is to create 5 buttons in each layout with same id. Then you can create a static method in one of your activities called, for example, `initializeButton()`. This method should inflate your button. You can call this method from every activity, and it should do the job. Hope this helps.

Comment: In this i have to  add it on all the five Activity.I dont need this i have to add it on one view.How can i?

Comment: @karthi, Anyway you will need to inflate the layout in each activity you're creating, so you'll inflate your button in each onCreate(). There is no way of passing it.

Comment: @karthi, You have a title bar above your application, why do you need another one?